# Can not find entry point in DB2 .NET dll (db2app.dll) from a different project in the same solution

Tags: .net, vb.net, db2

I am using IBM.Data.DB2.dll v9.0.0.2 (which accesses db2app.dll?) with VS 2008. I have created a user control which uses a DB2 connection for data to display. This appears to work fine when running the user control directly.

The problem enters when I either:

- create a test project for the user control
- create a windows form project and attempt to add the new control

The specific error message that I get is this:
[image]

The line of code it seems to be tripping over is creating the connection:

```
_db2Connection = New DB2Connection("SERVER=aaa.bbb.com:#####;" _
                                               & "Database=DBName;" _
                                               & "UID=username;PWD=password")
```

Which, again, works fine in the original project it is contained in. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `db2app.dll` in the `bin/Debug/` folder for the application that's executing? If not, try copying it there and see if that fixes the issue and let us know. That'll help in debugging.

Comment: It already is being copied locally for the user control project. But it isn't there for the other two. I tried copying to the other two projects - still no go. As far as I can tell, it's not having trouble finding the DLL, it can't find the entry point for some reason.

Comment: I take that back, IBM.Data.DB2.dll is what was in the user control project. Tried copying db2app.dll to all folders. Still no go.

Comment: Copying `IBM.Data.DB2.dll` doesn't do the trick?

Comment: That was what I had mis-copied the first time.

Comment: Are your projects using different .NET frameworks? [This thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013860810) on DeveloperWorks seems to indicate that using different versions of the framework could cause issues. Also, do you only have the v9 client package installed, or do you also have v8? Finally, what kind of DB2 server are you connecting to, the differences between DB2 for mainframe (z/OS), distributed (Linux/Unix/Windows), and iSeries could change the answer.  (Aside, hi @JeffBridgman )

Comment: It doesn't look like you can set a target framework for the compile of a test project like you can for other projects. I learned something new. At any rate, I created the projects all in the same solution using the default for VS2008 sp1 which is framework 3.5.

Comment: I bit the bullet and uninstalled DB2 completely and re-installed it. Seems to have fixed my issue. Although it looks like the DB2 Add-in integration with VS2008 is no longer working. (Don't really care, would rather have my tests working than the add-in.) Still, it's weird to see the code work in one project and not another. If anyone else has experience with this, I'd still like to get to the heart of the error.

Spoke too soon. Now the original project is throwing an error: "Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.0.0.2,... or one of its dependencies. Invalid pointer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got everything working by un-installing everything related to Visual Studio (2008, 2010, 2012) and DB2 (IBM Data Server Driver Package - IBMDBCL1, IBM database add-ins for Visual Studio, & DB2 Express-C) and re-installing VS2008 and using V10.5 of the DB2 install package. I think there must have been a version mismatch between the add-in and the DB2 drivers.

Although the references in VB are still to the same version IBM.Data.DB2.dll v9.0.0.2

Just putting it out here in the hopes it could help someone else.